Can a differentiable function have a limit approaching infinity without having a derivative of infinity at the same point.
Can a function exist such that it has a domain of at least $(0, \infty)$ and within this interval also be differentiable at all points but satisfying $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) \neq \pm \infty$ at the same time?
Currently I have $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}(1+\frac{1}{2}sin(\frac{1}{x}))$
It has a limit of infinity at 0, while the limit of the derivative does not approach $\pm \infty$. I am unsure how to prove this, though.
My line of reasoning for creating the function was as follows:
Does a function approaching infinity have to be increasing or decreasing on the interval from a to $\delta$?
No. how do I construct something that isn't?
First I know $x + xsin(x)$ approaches $\pm \infty$ and 0
If I substitute $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x$ I should have what I need
But the function does not oscillate infinitely approaching 0, so I should put $\frac{1}{x}$ inside $sin(x)$
But now the function oscillates between 0 and $\infty$, so I should divide $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ by 2 so that it still approaches $\infty$
I am not sure if there is anything wrong with my line of reasoning.

Why not try proving that $f$ satisfies the initial requirements to convince yourself that your intuition is right?
